# Can we extend DDC to three rounds and get more information?

Tags: compilers, security

During [diverse double-compiling](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.5534), they say that it is proof that either all the compilers are subverted, or none of them, but they cannot say which one is subverted. In my studies of the technique I tried to draw a figure how we can compile three rounds and after that, knowing exactly which one is compromised. But do you think it is correct reasoning from me?[image]

I tend to think, and maybe claim, that if the file in box 8 is different from the file in box 9, then it is necessarily compiler B that is buggy or contains malware.